# How do you create a thread, wait for it to do something specific, and then continue?

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket

I'm a bit new to Threads and can't seem to find exactly what I need online. The problem I am trying to solve is having multiple clients connect to a server, and running simultaneously. The number of clients is arbitrary, and a client should be able to connect at any time. To do this, I created the "Server" class which stores all the information about clients and is essentially the hub. I then have a helper class "UserThread," which implements Runnable and each UserThread can connect to a client. The problem I'm having is running multiple UserThreads simultaneously. Here is the code I currently have in the Server class for creating new UserThreads:

```
int currentPort = 1;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(currentPort);
        System.out.println("waiting for user to connect");
        Thread thread = new Thread(new UserThread(currentPort, this));
        thread.start();
        // A
        System.out.println("Connected");
        currentPort++;
    }
```

And here is the run method of UserThread:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        // B
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // down here doesn't effect my question so I excluded it
 }
```

I've labeled A and B in each one as comments. Initially when I was just testing with a single instance of UserThread running, I was able to replace A with "user.join();" This allowed the UserThread to run, but it stopped the while loop in Server. What I need, and may not exist the way I think it does, is some code to put in spot A that pauses the while loop until line B is called in UserThread. Then, both the Server and the new UserThread will both continue working simultaneously. If another user connects to the Server, another UserThread is created and all three continue to work. This should function for an arbitrary number of connected Users.
So far, I've tried replacing A with "user.wait()" and B with "this.notify()" but I don't think either of those do what I think they do. user.wait() ended up throwing "java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner". I tried then surrounding it with synchronized(user){} from a post I saw online but it still threw the same exception. At this point I'm pretty lost, so I'd like any insight possible. Do such lines of code exist to replace A and B, or am I approaching this problem in the completely wrong way? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of problems here:

### wait and notify

They would work here, but you can't call `x.wait/notify/notifyAll` unless you are within a `synchronized(x)` block. While `x.wait()` is waiting, you won't be holding that lock; you'll regain it once wait() returns.

### This isn't how to do servers

You make 1 single `ServerSocket` object, and one thread that will repeatedly do this:

- Call `accept()` on the serversocket object.
- Create a new thread; hand it the `Socket` that comes out of that call.
- Start that thread
- Go back to the beginning

Your solution is bizarre, and really requires you to fire up all threads simultaneously, listening to a bevy of ports (for no particular reason), and thus limiting incoming connections rather severely.

Then, if you want any of those threads to wait until something happens, use wait/notify, or better yet, stuff from j.u.c. For example, [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) lets you safely wait until X things happen, for example, have the user threads countdown the latch, and have some other thread wait until 4 countdowns have occurred: That's how you'd write software that waits until 4 connections have come in.

A full tutorial on how to do multithreading in java is *just a tad* beyond the scope of a reasonable SO question.

Comment: Right, I entered with the assumption that each client had to connect to a new port. I have it all working with the far simpler solution now, thanks for the advice.